# ServiceController can't start service on Windows 10 1709+ when using an IPv4 address and non-admin user

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-10, servicecontroller

We have a Windows Service that sits and monitors our main Windows Service. It can query the service status, stop, start, and restart the service as required. It does so using the [ServiceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .Net.

When installed using our installer, the services can be configured to use an existing Windows User account, or a new account can be created for the services. This user can be an Admin or a Non-Admin user. Either way, when installed, the monitor service is configured to start Automatically and the Main service is set to Manual, and the configured user account is explicitly granted all of the required permissions to control the Main service. I have double checked the DACL and confirmed that the user does indeed have permission.

Most of the time, the two services are installed on the same machine, but it is possible that they could be on different machines, so when new'ing up the `ServiceController` we pass in the service name and the IP address of the machine.

The issue is, on calling `ServiceController.Start()` we get the following Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open MyServiceName service on computer '127.0.0.1'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32 desiredAccess)
>
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
>
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
>   ).

This happens only when the configured user is non-admin, using an IPv4 address, and *only* on Windows 10 since the 1709 update. This exception does not occur on any previous version of Windows, including *all* previous versions of Windows 10 (and yes, I have tested all of them, urgh).
It also seems that the exception does not happen when using the hostname of the machine or "localhost", only when using an IPv4 address such as "127.0.0.1" or the actual IP of the machine.

The issue can be reproduced using the following little console program:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ServiceStartTest
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            try
            {
                var serviceController = new ServiceController("MyServiceName", "127.0.0.1");
                serviceController.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception caught: {ex}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }        
    }
}
```

Run as a non-administrator user and replace `"MyServiceName"` with the installed name of a service you can control.

I'd really like to know what changed in 1709 that caused this and if there's a way around it other than using hostnames.

Comment: Well, this is not a .NET problem (which is not surprising). The code calls `OpenSCManager(machine, null, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT)`, then `OpenService(manager, "service", SERVICE_START)`. This is just what it should do, and all Win32 applications that try the same thing likewise fail. A simpler reproduction (from the command line) is `sc \\127.0.0.1 start wuauserv` (if Windows Update is not yet running). This will fail with an access denied, whereas `sc \\localhost start wuauserv` will not (assuming the default access rights have not been changed).

Comment: A reasonable workaround is to use `IPAddress.IsLoopback` to test for this, and substitute in `Environment.MachineName` instead. This requires minimal changes to the code (whether caller or callee). Obviously, though, this doesn't work with a non-loopback address, and doing a reverse DNS lookup may not be desirable.